# Reveal view when swiping a prototype table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

What I am trying to do is reveal a hidden menu when swiping on a `UITableViewCell`.
I have no idea how to do it, any guidance will be appreciated.

Here is an image so that you get an idea:

[Image http://imageshack.com/a/img855/9134/j6k8.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img855/9134/j6k8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can do it by using custom cell i give the ruff idea and sample code how to achieve this,
first create a new file objective-c, and name it as `CustomCell` subclass of  `UITableViewCell` and in `CustomCell.h` file

i took some dummy views and labels

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *optionsView; //this is your options to show when swiped
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *mainVIew; //this is your view by default present on top of options view
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *messageLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *optionsLabel;
@end
```

in `CustomCell.m`

```
 #import "CustomCell.h"

 @implementation CustomCell

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
       //since we are not using the xib we hav to initilise hear
       _optionsView = [[UIView alloc]init];
       _mainVIew    = [[UIView alloc]init];


       _optionsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
       _mainVIew.backgroundColor    = [UIColor redColor];

       _optionsView.alpha = 0.0f;
       _mainVIew.alpha     = 1.0f;


       _messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
       _optionsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

       [_optionsView addSubview:_optionsLabel]; //hear u can add image view or buttons to options view i just added the label
       [_mainVIew addSubview:_messageLabel];

       //add the gesture to main view
       UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(whenSwiped:)];
       swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
       [_mainVIew addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];//add it to main view


       UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeReverse = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(whenSwipedReversed:)];
       swipeReverse.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
       [_optionsView addGestureRecognizer:swipeReverse]; //add it to options view so that user can swipe back



        [self.contentView addSubview:_optionsView]; //first add the optionsVIew
        [self.contentView addSubview:_mainVIew]; //then main view

     }
     return self;
   }

 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

  - (void)layoutSubviews
 {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    _optionsView.frame = self.bounds;
    _mainVIew.frame    = self.bounds;

    _messageLabel.frame = _mainVIew.bounds;
    _optionsLabel.frame = _optionsView.bounds;

    _optionsView.alpha = 0.0f;
   _mainVIew.alpha    = 1.0f;

 }

  //handle swipe call backs in cell only and make a delegate to controller about the button actions of options view
 - (void)whenSwiped:(id)sender
  {
    CGRect frameRect = _mainVIew.frame;
    frameRect.origin.x = 300.0f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
      _mainVIew.frame = frameRect;
      _optionsView.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
  }

 - (void)whenSwipedReversed:(id)sender
  {
     CGRect frameRect = _mainVIew.frame;
     frameRect.origin.x = 0.0f;
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        _mainVIew.frame = frameRect;
        _optionsView.alpha = 0.0f;
      }];
  }

  @end
```

in view controller import `#import "CustomCell.h"`

in datasource method of tableview

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   CustomCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];
   if(Cell == nil)
   {
       Cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
   }
   Cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   Cell.optionsLabel.text = @"options";
   Cell.messageLabel.text = @"swipe me";

   return Cell;

 }
```

above is example, hope this helps u .. :)
and comment if don't get

Comment: Thats right what i needed, i used it with my own CustomCells that i already had and added the gesture and it worked. Really thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some guidance:

1. Each UITableViewCell could have two views, one on top of the other. The top-most view is what is shown by default, and the bottom-most view is what you call the "hidden menu."
2. You will need to register a UISwipeGestureRecognizer in your storyboard that manages the table cells you are showing above. You will create an IBAction for that gesture recognizer in your custom UITableViewCell class. In that action, you will handle the swipes that occur and then displace the top-most view of the cell by your desire amount, up to a maximum displacement (in the x-direction).

If you need more than this, let me know and I'll provide more info. I can't tell from your original question just how experienced you are, e.g., do you know how to create UITableViews with custom UITableViewCells?

UPDATE:

Make sure that you are creating a XIB file that houses your custom UITableViewCell. Then you can easily add the UISwipeGestureRecognizer to the XIB, and connect it to an IBAction in your cell class. In your UIViewController, you will register the XIB with a reuse identifier and populate your UITableView this way.

Comment: Yes, i know how to create UITableViews with custom UITableViewCells but i dont know how to register the UISwipeGEstureRecognizer because when i add the gesture to the UITAbleViewCell i get an error saying i cant add a UISwipeGEstureRecognizer to a prototype cell... if you can, i would need a little more help with swiping the hidden UIView and pushing the normal one.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to provide a little more context.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but whats a XIB?

Comment: A simple Google search will yield many helpful responses to that question. But my guess is that you may need to do some reading on iOS development before trying to accomplish what you're trying to do with that menu.